# SCSS particles animation - create at random position, but move all particles in the same direction

Tags: css, animation, sass, particles

I'm fairly new to SCSS so hopefully someone can help me out.
I'm trying to move particles in the same direction (down), but because all the particles are placed randomly their destination also ends up random.

I would like to keep random placement, but once they are placed I want them all going in the same direction (down) and not in the random direction. I don't know how to do that without loosing random positioning generated with steps.

I know how to do this in CSS, but that would require specifying every path manually, which will be my final solution if I can get it to work with SCSS, unless someone can help me out?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/animalbear/Lg7jdh3x/1/) to show how it's behaving, but this is the part where random steps are created:

SCSS

```
@for $i from 1 through $dot-count {
  &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
    animation-name: move-path-#{$i};
    &:before {
      animation-duration: random(5000) + 5000ms, random(1000) + 7000ms;
      animation-delay: random(6000) + 500ms, 0s;
    }
  }
  $steps: random(15) + 10;
  @keyframes move-path-#{$i} {
    @for $step from 0 through $steps {
      #{$step / $steps * 100%} {
        transform: translateX(random(100) - 50vw)
          translateY(random(100) - 50vh)
          scale(random(70) / 100 + 0.3);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want each dot to start in a random place but after that it is to fall straight down, or is it to fall down in a random pattern but always downwards?

Comment: Yeah the first thing. To be placed in a random spot and then to fall down.

Comment: he meant the direction of the fall "straight down fall" (like | ) or "random fall down" (like \ / | )

Comment: I see, yeah, straight down like |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a random variable common to all your particles, use it to position your particles and then move them according to their step number and not randomly.

```
html {
  font-size: 30vmax / 1920 * 100;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

// Stars
$dot-color: #fff;
$dot-count: 35;

#milky-way {
  width: 100%;
}

.sky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dot {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.08rem;
  height: 0.08rem;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  animation: 160s ease both infinite alternate;
  &:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: $dot-color;
    transform-origin: -1rem;
    animation: lighting ease both infinite, auto-rotating ease both infinite;
  }
  @for $i from 1 through $dot-count {
    // Random variable common to all particles
    $random: random(100);
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      animation-name: move-path-#{$i};
      &:before {
        animation-duration: random(5000) + 5000ms, random(1000) + 7000ms;
        animation-delay: random(6000) + 500ms, 0s; // less than max duration
      }
    }
    $steps: random(15) + 10;
    @keyframes move-path-#{$i} {
      
      @for $step from 0 through $steps {
        
        #{$step / $steps * 100%} {
          // first translation is depending on a common random, second is depending on the step number
          transform: translateX($random - 50vw) translateX($step * $step * 150px)
            translateY($random - 50vh) translateY($step * $step * 150px)
            scale(random(70) / 100 + 0.3);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@keyframes lighting {
  0%,
  30%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.3rem 0.05rem $dot-color;
  }
}
@keyframes auto-rotating {
  to {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for posting your answer! Particles are now moving down and to the right. I was able to make them all go straight down by changing translateX to 0px and  translateY to 500px, they are now moving as they should. But now particles seem to spawn somewhat diagonally and animation stops after few seconds (even though it has infinite attribute), do you by any chance know how to fix that as well? Thank you either way, you really helped me a lot!

Comment: Hello, sorry I don't have much time to investigate further, I hope you'll understand.

Comment: Yes of course, I appreciate that you helped at all. I decided to make this with plain CSS so I'm good.